# Routing optional parameters with dashes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've made an routing definition like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("ProductSearch", "Search-{MainGroup}-{SubGroup}-{ItemType}",
   new {
    controller = "Product",
    action = "Search",
    MainGroup = "", SubGroup = "", ItemWebType = ""});
```

It is not working if the parameters are empty.
Actually it resolves the url, so Url.Action method resolves the path "Search-12--" but the link is not working, so the GET of the page is not working

With slashes it is working the Url.Action method makes "Search/12"

```
"Search/{MainGroup}/{SubGroup}/{ItemType}"
```

Is it somehow possible to correct it?

I made a sample with the default mvc project:
Only added:
before default route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(DefaultSearch", "Search-{MainGroup}-{Subgroup}-{ItemType}",
        new {controller = "Home",action = "About", MainGroup = "", 
              Subgroup = "", ItemType = ""});
```

in Home/index.aspx:

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("About", "Home", new {maingroup = "2", subgroup = "", itemType = ""}) %>">
    Search</a>
```

In HomeController:

```
public ActionResult About(string maingroup, string subgroup, string itemtype)
{
  return View();
}
```

Click on the link and 404

Answer (score 1):

What version do you use? in mvc 2 you can use `UrlParameter.Optional` as default values for routes.

Comment: Unfortunately MVC 1. I solved my problem totally by totally override the RouteBase class' GetVirtualPath and GetRouteData functions